# encrypt with stunnel

Tags: mysql

I'm running OTRS on a CentOS server and the MySQL DB is running on a remote server, on CentOS as well. OTRS does not support an encrypted connection with MySQL hence the connection is not encrypted. I would like to use stunnel to encrypt the connection but I fail to configure it. MySQL is using the default port 3306.

OTRS = 10.0.0.4
MySQL = 10.0.0.3

```
#Sample stunnel configuration on OTRS Server

#Provide the full path to your certificate-key pair file

cert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/stunnel.pem

#lock the process into a chroot jail

chroot = /var/run/stunnel

# and create the PID file in this jail

pid = /stunnel.pid

#change the UID and GID of the process for security reasons
setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody

#enable client mode
client = yes


socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
#socket = r:TCP:NODELAY=1

[mysqls]
accept = 0.0.0.0:3306
connect = 10.0.0.3:3307
```

And the config file on the database server:

```
#Sample configuration file for MySQL

#Provide the full path to your certificate-key pair file
cert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/stunnel.pem

#Allow only TLS, thus avoiding SSL
sslVersion = TLSv1

#lock the process into a chroot jail
chroot = /var/run/stunnel

#change the UID and GID of the process for security reasons
setuid = nobody
setgid = nobody

pid = /stunnel.pid
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

#Configure our secured MySQL Server
[mysqls]

accept = 3307
connect = 3306
```

I guess that the part in the stunnel config file on the OTRS Server is wrong. Any ideas?

> accept = 0.0.0.0:3306

Comment: "I fail to configure it" "I guess that the part in the stunnel config file ... is wrong" It will be far more useful if you explained how you know there is a problem, like content of error messages, etc. This is also not looking like a security question.

Comment: Its not OTRS which does the MySQL TLS stuff - its Perl - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566966/perl-dbimysql-connection-over-ssl-fails

Comment: OTRS is written in Perl. To make OTRS capable of connecting to MySQL via TLS the code would need to be changed - this would void the support contract. Hence my only option is to use stunnel.

Comment: You could also do this via a Point 2 Point vpn connection that is much easier to set up btw

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

I've changed the database host value in the Config.pm file from the real IPv4 address of the database server to 127.0.0.1:

[image]

Then I've configured the stunnel.conf on the OTRS box to listen on 127.0.0.1:3306 (OTRS by default connects to the standard MySQL port) and to connect to the real IPv$ address of the database host but on port 3307:

[image]

On the database server the stunnel.conf looks like this:

[image]

Running tcpdump on the db server and analyzing the .pcap in Wireshark it shows that the connection is encrypted and OTRS still works:

[image]

Whether the stunnel.conf files are good constructed this I don't know yet, but for example I've read that chroot shouldn't be used longer but will dig more deep into it.